# How to explain what takes place during certain times in some movie

Tags: sentence-construction

Suppose, you're watching some movie, and you want to tell someone what goes down during certain times in the movie.

Near the beginning- Five minutes in the movie, this happens.
Or
Five minutes from the start of the movie, this happens.

Near the end- Five minutes from the end of the movie, this happens.

Would the constructions above be enough to get across what the speaker is trying to get across?

Comment: **In the beginning** and **at the end** seems correct to me.

Answer (score 1):

"From the start" and "from the end" are fine. You could also use "beginning" instead of "start". Instead of "five minutes in the movie", you should say "five minutes into the movie".